# Symfony2 Doctrine2 Many To Many Form not Saving Entities

Tags: forms, symfony, many-to-many, doctrine-orm

I am having some trouble with a many to many relationship. I have `Users` and `Assets`. I would like to be able to assign users to an asset on the asset page.

The code below displays a list of users when creating/editing an asset, however changes made to the user checkboxes do not save, while the rest of the data is persisted.

If I add an entry to users_assets through the mysql client, these changes are shown in the asset list.

**User**

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Asset", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $assets;
}
```

**Asset**

```
class Asset
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="assets")
     */
    private $users;
}
```

**AssetType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $form = $builder
        ->add('users', null, array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ))
        ->getForm();

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you chanage `null` to `EntityType`? What do you mean by null?!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For some reason I had to switch the doctrine mappings to get this to work:

```
Asset:
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Adaptive\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="assets")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_assets")
 */
private $users;

User:
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Splash\SiteBundle\Entity\Asset", mappedBy="users")
 */
private $assets;
```

Now when I save the asset it saves the users associated. I did not need to define builder->add as an entity or collection. I simply pass it null and it uses the mapping info to fill in the entity info:

```
AssetType:
->add('users', null, array('expanded' => "true", "multiple" => "true"))
```

Not exactly sure why I needed to have the inversedBy and JoinTable info on the Asset vs The User but it seems to be working now!

Thanks For The Suggestions!!!

Comment: I was having similar problems. Suggestions to others: make sure all your singulars/plurals are what they're supposed to be, and if either of your entities has a multi-term name (e.g. `CoolDude`), you might benefit by knowing that the Doctrine default is to assume your table name is just the lower-cased version of that, e.g. `cooldude`. If it's actually `cool_dude`, I think you'll have to explicitly set that. You can see how in the Doctrine docs. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Problem is when you want a similar form on the inverse side: it would not work.

Comment: @slaapwagen Same problem here. It won't work on the inverse side. Did you find a solution to this problem already?

Answer (score 24):

Weird enough I faced the same problem in 2016 and still had hard time finding the solution. I will share it for future googlers:

The problem is that what symfony essentially does when you save the form is this:

`$asset->getUsers()->add($user)`

And because you're on the inverse side of the relation it won't persist your changes.

What you really need is to make so that it calls this:

`$asset->addUser($user)`

Where addUser() is defined the following way on the Asset entity:

```
public function addUser(User $user) 
{
    //add to the inverse side
    $this->users->add($user);

    //add on the owning side (only this is persisted)
    $user->addAsset($this); //$user->assets->add($asset);
}
```

---

So in order to make symfony use that `$asset->addUser()` method, you should set

**`'by_reference' => false`**

on your `users` field for `AssetType` form.

More about this setting here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#by-reference

Remember you also need to define `removeUser()` method in the same way (so that it removes entity from the owning relation)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was wondering, doing some retro-posting, why no one wrote this and finally came you with yours. Nice one.

Comment: **Asset** is owning side here, thus this conflicts with [Doctrine Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association)

Comment: @Trix Thanks, I've just checked it again and there indeed was a confusion of user/assets. I made an edit - solution is still the same, I only adjusted variable names to be consistent.

Answer (score 17):

> Not exactly sure why I needed to have the inversedBy and
>   JoinTable info on the Asset vs The User but it
>   seems to be working now!

The reason why your changes has been ignored is that doctrine persists only changes by the owning side of a relation (like @Florian said).

This is the link to Doctrine's documentation where this behaviour is explained: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Answer (score 4):

At first you should drop backslash prefix in annotations (see notice [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#runtime-vs-development-mapping-validation)).

And you need to use entity field type:

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AdaptiveUserBundle:User',
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'collection' field type in your form.

```
$builder->add('users', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new UserType(),
    'prototype' => true,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true
));
```

You need to create the `UserType()` form first obviously.

Here is all the info you will need, including code samples:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: I thought by passing null it would assume this is the type, through my doctrine mappings. I have a similar setup using categories on the assets and it works great. This is the code I have to populate the category collections: ->add('categories', null, array('expanded' => "true", "multiple" => "true" ))... also I do not need to add crud functionality for users in the asset, rather I simply need to be able to assign current users to that asset

Comment: Indeed, doctrine's from extension adds a guesser based on metadata. If you have correctly defined your ManyToMany association, the type guesser will configure your field as `collection`. By *correctly*, I mean that the **owner** of the association has to be the `Asset` in your case, that's why you had to invert your mapping.

Comment: Whats the problem with `EntityType`+`Expanded`+`Multiple`?