# Saving ManyToMany relation with entity field (owning/inversed sides)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm using the [Managing Roles in the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database)
 example to save my users and roles to a database. I want to make a `User` form with a `Roles` field with `multiple=true`, so I can use a checkbox to select all roles for a specific user. I also want a `Role` form with a `Users` field, so I can select users for that role.

Saving the `ManyToMany` relationship with an entity field didn't work well, so I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102063/symfony2-doctrine2-many-to-many-form-not-saving-entities). The given answer does solve the problem, but there is still a problem. The `User` form only selects one `Role`, while the `Role` form selects (and saves) multiple Users. Saving the ManyToMany relationship only works at the owning side. This problem is [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102063/symfony2-doctrine2-many-to-many-form-not-saving-entities?rq=1#comment13406098_9116358).

How can I save a ManyToMany relationship on both sides?

I've used this code to make my form:

**UserType.php:**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'UserBundle:Role',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

**Form data**

When posting the form (checked multiple Roles), only one Role is posted:

```
_method:PUT
acme_appbundle_user[username]:paul
acme_appbundle_user[email]:paul@*****.nl
acme_appbundle_user[isActive]:1
acme_appbundle_user[roles][]:3
acme_appbundle_user[_token]:cknUf8psN1k9FBN9GLY4i7bY0Y6FugNhjgudkpKKw-k
```

[image: Screenshot form+console]

The rendered HTML form seems so be right:

```
iv id="bundle_user_roles" class="col-lg-9">
    <label class=" checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="bundle_user_roles_1" name="bundle_user[roles][]" class="" value="1" checked="checked"/>
        Administrator
    </label>
    <label class=" checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="bundle_user_roles_3" name="bundle_user[roles][]" class="" value="3" checked="checked"/>
        User
    </label>
</div>
```

**Solution**

I found the problem. I was using a function to post all the data with $.ajax(), but that function didn't pass the array's very well. I removed that useless piece of code. I found the solution, but I will continue to look for the developer that gave me that useless code ;-).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if you synchronize your relations via setter like explain [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/working-with-associations.html#synchronizing-bidirectional-collections), it should always work but keep in mind it's your responsibility to maintain this sync :)

EDIT: I mean you're code should look like:

```
class User
{
    // ...

    function setRoles(array $role)
    {
        $this->roles->clear();

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $this->addRole($role);
        }
    }

    function addRole(Role $role)
    {
        $this->roles->add($role);

        // Bidirectional synchronization
        if (!$role->getUsers()->contains($this)) {
            $role->addUser($this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I just give you the example for the User class but you need to sync the bidirectional relation the same way in the Role class.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I've used this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database. Do you think I've to change that code?

Comment: Unfortunatly, that doesn't help. It seems that the form doesn't post the right data. I updated my question with the new information.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. It isn't the right answer to the question, but given the fact that I didn't debug my code very well that isn't your fault ;-). Thanks for helping me!

Comment: To be honest, with your additional explanation, I don't know what is wrong :s

Comment: I was using this example: http://codemonkeys.be/2013/01/ajaxify-your-symfony2-forms-with-jquery/. Using ``$.each( $form.serializeArray()) { } `` caused the problem.

Comment: AFAIR, just do `$form.serialize()` :)